# GraphFrames and Label propagation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, graphframes

As I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_Propagation_Algorithm), the **label propagation** algorithm assigns labels to previously unlabeled nodes in a graph and, at the start of the algorithm, a (generally small) subset of the nodes have labels defined.

In the [documentation](https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html) of GraphFrames, they specified that *"Each node in the network is initially assigned to its own community"*.

Instead of initializing the labels with the vetex ID, is it possible to choose another attribute of the node? I try to propagate a label that is only defined on a few nodes in my graph.

Thanks for your help.